# Estoy tratando de renderizar objetos DOM HTML con Javascript dependiendo del tipo pero ando un tanto perdido

Tags: javascript, html5

```
let items = [
    {
        name: "Luis",
        price: 15
    },
    {
        name: "Amore",
        price: 100
    }
];


var elDiv = {
    name: 'div'
}
var elUl = {
    name: 'ul'
}
var elLi = {
    name: 'li'
}

var elP = {
    name: 'p'
}

function domFunctor(opciones, innerhtml){
    let dom = document.createElement(this.name);
    dom.className = opciones.className ? opciones.className : "";
    if (innerhtml.length) {
        innerhtml.map(item => dom.appendChild(item));
    }else{
        if (innerhtml.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            dom.innerHTML = innerhtml;
        }else{
            dom.appendChild(dom.innerHTML);
        }
    }

    return dom;
}
var div = domFunctor.bind(elDiv);
var ul = domFunctor.bind(elUl);
var li = domFunctor.bind(elLi);
var p = domFunctor.bind(elP);


function renderList(renderItem,items)
{
    return div(
        { className: 'list-container'},
        items.length
        ? ul('',items.map(renderItem))
        : p('','No items found')
    );
}
function formatCurrency(params) {
    return params;
}

const renderPriceItem = item => li('',formatCurrency(item.price));
const renderCustomerItem = item => li('',item.name);
renderPriceList = renderList.bind(null, renderPriceItem);
// renderCustomerItem = renderList.bind(null, renderCustomerItem);
(function () {
    let salida = renderPriceList(items);
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = salida;
})();
```

Devuelve error, y ya no se como solucionar, se que podría utilizar otras librerias y demás el chiste es hacerlo con vanilla.
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

#### Aqui el ejemplo de como debería quedar según sea ordenado por la función renderList

```
    <div class="list-container">
     <!-- DEPENDE SI LA LISTA TIENE DATOS: -->
      <ul>
        <!-- Depende del Tipo de Dato que se esté mostrando -->
         <li> dato 1</li>
         <li> dato 2</li>
         ...
         <li> dato n</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Si la lista no tiene datos -->
      <p>No items found</p>
    </div>
```

**Nota Importante:** Se que se puede hacer muy fácil, de otra manera, necesito que los Objetos DOM, se creen de manera dinámica, y además se puedan anidar:
**Por ejemplo:** div({ className: "container"}, div({ className: "fondoverde"}, ul("", ...)));

si saben de algún otro método sin utilizar librerias externas como Jquery, etc. agradezco mucho.

**El Propósito de este ejercicio es meramente educativo.**

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de como quieres que quede porfavor

Comment: @x-rw le puse el ejemplo de como debería salir el resultado, y algunas aclaraciones, dado que hacerlo por ejemplo con jquery es muy facil, si utilizamos $("#contenedor").html('<li> contenido etc...</li>'); en este ejercicio se utiliza Recursividad, Curry Functions, Functors, etc. Es el propósito, Gracias por comentar.